# Field is not writeable: Opportunity.PartnerAccountId

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

I am trying to update the field PartnerAccountId (Partner Account) on Opportunity object when a Lead is converted and a new Opportunity record is created.
I am doing this in Trigger Before Insert context.

So there already exists a Flow in which Opportunity.PartnerAccountId is being updated in before save context and it works there but as I am moving that flow logic to a trigger and write a simple line of code:

```
for(Opportunity opp : newOpportunities){
  opp.PartnerAccountId = opp.some_field_with_accountid;
}
```

This doesn't let me save the class and throws error in developer console.

**Field is not writeable: Opportunity.PartnerAccountId**

I am wondering what could be the reason here? I've checked FLS and Sharing Settings and all seems in place.
Also, how this fields is writable in Flow but not in Apex?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot populate the Partner Account directly on an Opportunity. Instead, you must insert a Partner record linked to the Account and the Opportunity. For example:

```
Partner p = new Partner();
p.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
p.AccountToId = opp.some_field_with_accountid;
p.IsPrimary = true;
p.Role = 'Partner Role'; //change this based on your requirements
insert p;
```

Because you're inserting a new record, you should do this in an `after` trigger instead of `before`.